# Found a grocery list - used it for handwriting reading practice. Corrections?

Tags: handwriting

I'm sure the first one is wrong and definitely couldn't figure out the one with fish. Fairly certain of the ones with pork.

西乳柿, 小葱, 排骨, ?鱼, 龙骨, 山药, 豆子, 猪腰, 猪肺?

[image: HandwrittenGrocery List]

Comment: Hey，thanks for the downvotes. Have a nice life! :-) :-) :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My list of corrections:

1. 西红柿 (tomato)
2. 侧 鱼. As for what fish this is, I had to [google](https://www.google.com/search?q=%E4%BE%A7%20%E9%B1%BC&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a&channel=sb&gfe_rd=cr&ei=DJhWU6DYEILRrQeexoDYDg).
3. 豆干 (dried bean curd) rather than 豆子, which is the whole bean itself]
4. 猪肝 (pig liver) rather than 猪肺 (pig lung)

Comment: I guess 侧鱼 means either flatfish/flounder (比目鱼) or tilapia (which I don't know the Chinese name)

Comment: My google says it is 鲫鱼 （Golden fish，Crucian carp）